# Date и time picker для Firefox

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Нужно на форме добавить возможность выбора даты и времени(в одном поле).
Кажется такое без проблем работает в Chrome и Edge, но в Firefox можно выбрать лишь только дату.
Можно ли как то это исправить или найти аналог?

Comment: Кажется, или работает? Вы проверяли? Можете создать и показать пример, где в Chrome все работает, а в Firefox нет? Укажите, какие версии браузеров при этом используются.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте Bootstrap datetimepicker